# Angular2 Http post 400

Tags: json, angular

I have this service:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpserviceService {
  baseUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/";
  headers = new Headers({
    'accept': 'application/json'
  });

 post(url: string,  data: any): Observable<any> {

    //send post request
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+url, JSON.stringify(data))
      .map(this.extractData) //this works
      .catch(this.handleError); //this as well
  }
}
```

and when I subscribe to that method:

```
user: User = {
  username: "test",
  password: "12345"
}
authUrl: string = 'user/auth';
return this.http.post(this.authUrl, user)
  .subscribe(data => {
    //console.log(data);
  });
```

I'm getting an

> Status Code:400 Bad Request

What can be wrong?

When I request using `postman` everything works ok

[image]

Comment: Well, this could be a CORS issue, show us the stacktrace of the error in your angular app.

Comment: The server should send a proper error message explaining why your data is invalid. If it doesn't, it should at least log it. If it doesn't, you could debug it. My point being: check yur server. Also, you didn't post the complete client code, so we don't know what you're doing with the headers, and specifying the content type and calling JSON.stringify() is useless, since Angular does it for you when sending an object directly.

Comment: @camaron http://i.imgur.com/4muLKwM.png that's it

Comment: @gsiradze so where is content type in request???

Comment: Well, for a start, you're sending JSON, but your content type is text/plain. Second you're not showing the content of the response.

Comment: thanks guys for help

Comment: @camaron CORS is never bad request by the way

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat you are right, it's a 500, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postman i see that you have 1 header. Which you are not sending in angular

Try following, headers should go as a third parameter

```
post(url: string,  data: any): Observable<any> {

    //send post request
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+url, JSON.stringify(data),  {headers: this.headers})
      .map(this.extractData) //this works
      .catch(this.handleError); //this as well
  }
```

Comment: it's Content-Type application/json and I have that in code

Comment: I added that as header but result is same

Comment: @gsiradze you have only initialization of headers, but you are not sending them, see my update

Comment: I dont know who downvoted but your edited answer works. thanks a lot it took my 2 hours

Comment: @gsiradze It must work. As i said you were not sending headers :) dont forget to mark as resolved.